# Cannot have aggregate function in expression

Tags: sql, ms-access

Hi I am trying to do the qry below and I keep getting "Cannot have aggregate function in expression" error on the subqry sum line. Any way to make this work?

```
SELECT ID, 
    DateColumn, 
    Contamination, 
    BrokenGlass, 
    OtherReasons, 
    SUM(Contamination) + SUM(BrokenGlass) + SUM(OtherReasons) AS Total, 
    SUM(Contamination) / Total AS Expr1,
    (SELECT SUM(Contamination)/ SUM(SUM(Contamination) + SUM(BrokenGlass) + SUM(OtherReasons))
     FROM tbltest T2
     WHERE T2.ID <= T2.ID) AS RunningSum
FROM tbltest
GROUP BY ID, DateColumn, Contamination, BrokenGlass, OtherReasons
```

Comment: You cannot do `SUM(SUM(` like that.

Comment: And beware this condition: `WHERE T2.ID <= T2.ID`

Comment: What are ou trying to do? You already have `SUM + SUM ...`, so why the outer `SUM`?

Comment: `WHERE T2.ID <= T2.ID`? Do you mean `WHERE T2.ID <= tbltest.ID`? Also, depending on your RDBMS, you may benefit from `SUM() OVER ()` rathern that this version - this will be extremely slow for even remotely large data-sets due to repeated calculations. *[And `SUM(SUM(Contamination) + SUM(BrokenGlass) + SUM(OtherReasons))` can just be `(SUM(Contamination) + SUM(BrokenGlass) + SUM(OtherReasons))`.]*

Comment: I need to somehow divide the running sum of contamination and the running sum of Total. So if Contamination row 1 = 7 and row 2 = 1 and total row1 = 10 and row2 = 1 it would divied 8/11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT ID,  
    DateColumn,  
    Contamination,  
    BrokenGlass,  
    OtherReasons,  
    SUM(Contamination) + SUM(BrokenGlass) + SUM(OtherReasons) AS Total,  
    SUM(Contamination) / Total AS Expr1, 

    /* CHANGED THIS LINE */
    (SELECT SUM(Contamination)/ (SUM(Contamination) + SUM(BrokenGlass) + SUM(OtherReasons))
     FROM tbltest T2 
     WHERE T2.ID <= T2.ID) AS RunningSum 

FROM tbltest 
GROUP BY ID, DateColumn, Contamination, BrokenGlass, OtherReasons
```

## Edited

The results being incorrect is a whole different problem than what was originally asked and I'm going to have to take a stab in the dark at this because I know nothing about your project, but here you go and maybe it can get you started in the right direction.

```
SELECT ID,
    DateColumn,
    Contamination,
    BrokenGlass,
    OtherReasons,
    SUM(Contamination) + SUM(BrokenGlass) + SUM(OtherReasons) AS Total,
    SUM(Contamination) / Total AS Expr1,
    (
         SELECT SUM(Contamination)/ (SUM(Contamination) + SUM(BrokenGlass) + SUM(OtherReasons))
         FROM tbltest T2 
         WHERE T2.ID <= tbltest.ID
    ) AS RunningSum
FROM tbltest
GROUP BY ID, DateColumn, Contamination, BrokenGlass, OtherReasons
```

Comment: It is giving me the wrong results each row is 0.588235 in the running total column

Comment: Copied `WHERE T2.ID <= T2.ID`.  Should probably be `WHERE T2.ID <= tbltest.ID`.

Answer (score 3):

I am guessing that you are using MS-Access based on the Expr1, try the following.  Replace the `Total` alias usage in the query and you cannot `SUM(SUM())`:

```
SELECT ID, 
    DateColumn, 
    Contamination, 
    BrokenGlass, 
    OtherReasons, 
    SUM(Contamination) + SUM(BrokenGlass) + SUM(OtherReasons) AS Total, 
    SUM(Contamination) / (SUM(Contamination) + SUM(BrokenGlass) + SUM(OtherReasons)) AS Expr1,
    (SELECT SUM(Contamination)/ (SUM(Contamination) + SUM(BrokenGlass) + SUM(OtherReasons))
     FROM tbltest T2
     WHERE T2.ID <= tbltest.ID) AS RunningSum  -- I think you want T2.ID <= tbltest.ID not T2.ID <= T2.ID
FROM tbltest
GROUP BY ID, DateColumn, Contamination, BrokenGlass, OtherReasons
```

Comment: Still not getting correct result? every rows value is .588235

Comment: @user1342164 can you edit your original post with some sample data and then the results that you need?

Comment: I need to somehow divide the running sum of contamination and the running sum of Total. So if Contamination row 1 = 7 and row 2 = 1 and total row1 = 10 and row2 = 1 it would divied 8/11

Comment: @user1342164 some sample data would be really helpful in this case. I have create partial sample data in a table but I can't really tell exactly what you want as the final product.

Answer (score 2):

Change your `sum(sum())` to just use the addition operator for the resulting sums:

```
--SUM(SUM(Contamination) + SUM(BrokenGlass) + SUM(OtherReasons)) 
(SUM(Contamination) + SUM(BrokenGlass) + SUM(OtherReasons))
```

In addition, don't attempt to reference an alias in the same `select` clause.  Either use a sub-query/derived table or just repeat the desired calculation for 'Total'.

```
--SUM(Contamination) / Total AS Expr1
SUM(Contamination) / (SUM(Contamination) + SUM(BrokenGlass) + SUM(OtherReasons))
```

Comment: It is giving me the wrong results each row is 0.588235 in the running total column

Comment: @user1342164 - As per my comment to your question...  `WHERE T2.ID <= T2.ID`? Do you mean `WHERE T2.ID <= tbltest.ID`?